# Best Practise in using OLEDB Source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledb, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SSIS, and I wondered what is considered the best practice when making a new table.
I want to make a table based on four other tables from the same database. However, I was wondering if it would be smarter to:

1. Use just one OLEDB Source and write the SQL code in there.
   or
2. Use 4 OLEDB Sources and sort and join them together to create the new table.

The goal is to get the new table in our ETL; the new table will use 2 or 3 columns from each source table.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using one OLEDB source with the joins done in the SQL query will give better performance. That will let the SQL Server query optimizer identify the most efficient way to load the data, which it's very good at doing. It also lets you identify bottlenecks like missing indexes in the query plan.

Using four different OLEDB sources then joining in SSIS has several possible cons:

- For the SSIS join to work, the data will need to be sorted, either in the query or using the SSIS Sort transformation. This adds an extra step to the processing, and SSIS Sorts don't perform well in my experience.
- You will probably load excess rows into SSIS that will be discarded by the join logic, unless every row will match in every table. This wastes resources on both servers and the network.
- I'd wager that the SSIS connection/query validation step for the four sources will take longer than a single source with a more complicated query.